# PKPass file generated in not opening in iOS devices

Tags: ios

Is anyone using `PKFileBasedSigningUtil` for generating the Apple pkpass file?

```
PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = new  PKSigningInformationUtil().loadSigningInformationFromPKCS12AndIntermediateCertificate(keyStorePath,  keyStorePassword, appleWWDRCA);

PKPassTemplateFolder passTemplate = new PKPassTemplateFolder(template_path);

PKFileBasedSigningUtil pkSigningUtil = new PKFileBasedSigningUtil();
byte[] signedAndZippedPkPassArchive = pkSigningUtil.createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, passTemplate, pkSigningInformation);
```

After getting the byte stream `signedAndZippedPkPassArchive`, writing into file and with format (abc.pkpass). 
This is expected to be opened in iOS devices, but not opening...But I am able to open in Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
If you aren't able to open your pass on an iPhone, plug the iPhone into a Mac and open the 'Console' application. On the left, you can select your iPhone. You will then be able to inspect any errors that occur while adding the pass: